# In jQuery plugin swipebox, links insert in image captions are not clickable on mobile, only in desktop, how to fix?

Tags: jquery, mobile

When using the jQuery plugin [SwipeBox](http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/), it is possible a add `<a>` as the caption.  In desktop, the caption's `<a href='...'>I am a caption</a>` is clickable.  However, when being accessed by a mobile device, the caption is not clickable and instead simply re-shows the caption everytime it is clicked.

Is it possible to make it follow the link properly?

The HTML appearing once a photo has been clicked:

```
<div class="slide current"><img src="http://domain.com/big-image.jpg"></div>
```

And

```
<a id="swipebox-caption" href="http://external.com/link" class="" style="transition: 0.5s; -webkit-transition: 0.5s;">Caption text</a>
```

The JS code from the plugin that is restricting the link from behind clicked starts like this:

```
$( 'body' ).bind( 'touchstart', function( event ) {

                $( this ).addClass( 'touching' );

                endCoords = event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0];
                startCoords.pageX = event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageX;
                startCoords.pageY = event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageY;

                $( '.touching' ).bind( 'touchmove',function( event ) {
                    event.preventDefault();
```

Is there a way to say, if the "touch" event is within the caption boudaries, then don't preventDefault behaviour and just click the link?

Thank you for any inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, needed to add this piece of code under the "Close" code:

```
                $('#swipebox-caption').bind(action, function () {
                window.location = goToUrl;
            });
```